# Android, on finish loading data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

How to show the Progressbar on start of the activity that contains recycler view which should be hidden once the recycler view loads the data from firebase database?

In **onCreate** method I am showing my ProgressBar but I don't know when should I hide it.

Can you guys give me some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Show me your code. Hint: you'd hide progressbar before setting recyclerview adapter

Comment: Post the code snippet of the activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`, to solve this, create a new object of `ProgressBar` and start showing it in the `onCreate()` method, or if you want add it directly in your .XML file and finally in your adapter class, override the following method:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should give your code. But i will try to explain with my code. (My code use LovelyProgressDialog as ProgressBar, because i like the UI. But you can change with your prefered ProgressBar)

First, you can show the progress bar in onCreate method (or onCreateView if you use Fragment instead of Activity).

```
@Override
public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Enter your code here
        dialogGetAllData.setCancelable(false)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_friend)
                .setTitle("Get all friend....")
                .setTopColorRes(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .show();
        getListData();
}
```

Then after you get all of the data from firebase (it means the dataSnapshot already null), you dismiss your progress bar

```
    private void getListData() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friend/" + StaticConfig.UID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                HashMap mapRecord = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Iterator listKey = mapRecord.keySet().iterator();
                while (listKey.hasNext()) {
                    String key = listKey.next().toString();
                    listFriendID.add(mapRecord.get(key).toString());
                }
            } else {
                dialogGetAllData.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```