# Firestore RecyclerView itemCount returns 0

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

So in my app, I'm using **Firestore Recyclerview** and I want to count the items showed in it. I've tried using ***registerAdapterDataObserver*** and ***onItemRangeInserted*** and they seem to work ONLY if there is at least one item in the `RecyclerView`. If there is none it doesn't even run.

Then, I've tried to implement the ***getItemCount()*** method but it always returns 0.

I have a class which is the adapter for the FirestoreRecyclerView.

```
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public JobsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Job> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull jobHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Job model) {
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getJobName());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getJobDescription());
    holder.textViewPostDate.setText(model.getJobDate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("adaptercount", "getItemCount: " + super.getItemCount());
    return super.getItemCount();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public jobHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.job_item, parent, false);
    return new jobHolder(v);
}

class jobHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;
    TextView textViewPostDate;

    public jobHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_desc);
        textViewPostDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_post_date);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here the ***getItemCount()*** method works perfectly, but when I try to call this method in another fragment it returns 0.

My ***RecyclerViewInit()*** method in the fragment:

```
Query query = prevJobRef.whereEqualTo("jobIsClosed", false).whereEqualTo("jobSenderID", userID);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Job> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Job>().
            setQuery(query, Job.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new JobsAdapter(options);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_activeJobs);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            Log.d("count", String.valueOf(adapter.getItemCount()));
       
        }
    });

    Log.d("count2", String.valueOf(adapter.getItemCount()));

  
}
```

I have a feeling that it's an amateur mistake and I hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried using ***registerAdapterDataObserver*** and ***onItemRangeInserted*** and they seem to work ONLY if there is at least one item in the `RecyclerView`. If there is none it doesn't even run.

That's the expected behavior since `onItemRangeInserted()` methods fires **only** when at least one item is inserted in the adapter. If there is no item to be inserted, the `onItemRangeInserted()` method will never fire. However, there are two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to override the `onChanged()` method in the same way you did `onItemRangeInserted()`, as it will be triggered even if there no items. And the second option that you have is to override the `onDataChanged()` method directly in your adapter class, as explained in my answer from the following post:

> [Android, on finish loading data from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004907/android-on-finish-loading-data-from-firebase)

The second option is possible only because you are using the Firebase-UI library.

Comment: Hey, Alex! Thank you for your answer, but none of these options seem to work. Whenever I call **getItemCount()** from my Fragment it returns 0, but works perfectly in my Adapter class.

Comment: You cannot simply use `getItemCount()` method because [the data from Cloud Firestore is loaded asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448654/5246885). If you say that it works perfectly in your adapter class, isn't your problem solved?

Comment: Not exactly, because I want to show/hide a TextView depending on the value of item count. That's what I cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: You can simply continue using that method in your adapter and create a callback to your activity. Basically, the method from the interface will be triggered according to your logic. For example, if `itemCount` in your adapter class is zero, then do some logic, otherwise do other logic.

Comment: How to get ItemCount after removing the item using FirestoreRecyclerOptions?

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive I think this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441563/firestore-paging-adapter-how-to-know-if-query-returns-0-results/57448654#57448654)** might help.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times I've had this error (and people I've seen on StackOverflow asking for this error) it turned out to be an error with the query.

If you got no errors on your console and logcat, but you still get 0 results, then it's definitely an error with your query I'd guess.

Make sure your query is correct. Check that the field "jobIsClosed" is a boolean, and that "jobSenderID" is a string. Also check your "prevJobRef" reference.

Answer (score 0):

This method below calculates the number of collections in firestore

```
 private void countQuestion(){

    ListenerRegistration collection = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("task").document(key).collection("question")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    int counter = value.size();
                   txtQuestionCount.setText("Question " + "(" + counter +")");
                }
            });
}
```